# Paginating through results in ElasticSearch when sorting by score not giving consistent results

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I have a very basic use case of paginating through the end of results when sorting by score (_score). But this does not return consistent results. For ex. if total matches are 50, ES will sometime return 45 (missing items), sometimes 55 duplicate items) and soon.

I already tried using preference option in search API to hit paginating ES requests to same shards but this does not work either. Link on what and why I tried preference: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-request-preference.html [https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/consistent-scoring.html#:~:text=Scores%20are%20not%20reproducibleedit&text=The%20reason%20is%20that%20Elasticsearch,copies%20of%20the%20same%20shard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/consistent-scoring.html#:%7E:text=Scores%20are%20not%20reproducibleedit&text=The%20reason%20is%20that%20Elasticsearch,copies%20of%20the%20same%20shard).

Has anyone else experienced same issue? Any solution? Or I am doing something wrong here?

PS: I already added tie-breaker sorting by id.
Also, I know about point in time (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/point-in-time-api.html). But my concern is the memory it will consume.

Comment: What ES version are you using?

Comment: I am using 7.9 version.

Comment: What `preference` value did you try?

Comment: Generally, matching documents shouldn't depend that much on the shard it hits. It could be a split brain issue actually. What's your cluster configuration (data/master nodes count)?

Comment: I used uuid's. For pagination I used same uuid. For new requests, new uuid.

Comment: 10 data nodes, 3 master nodes.

Comment: One thing I noticed is score are not reproducible even when using same uuid as preference. That could be the reason for inconsistent results in pagination.

Comment: Does `GET /_cat/nodes` return all of your nodes?